# Adding percentages by row to flextable columns

Tags: r, flextable

Suppose I have a row of counts by multiple groups, and a row for the total across all groups. How can I add in a percentage by row within the same column using flextable?

For example, in this simple example, the column for setosa would read "45 (31%)":

```
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(janitor)
library(flextable)
data(iris)

df<- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("Big Sepals"=sum(Sepal.Length>4.5)) %>%
  adorn_totals("row")
flextable(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add something to an existing visible column, use `append_chunks()` (use `prepend_chunks()` to insert before existing content):

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

df<- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("Big Sepals"=sum(Sepal.Length>4.5)) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = `Big Sepals`/sum(`Big Sepals`)*100)

flextable(df, col_keys = c("Species", "Big Sepals")) |> 
  append_chunks(j = "Big Sepals",
                as_i(" ("), 
                as_i(Percentage), 
                as_i("%)")) |> 
  autofit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(`Big Sepals` = sum(Sepal.Length > 4.5)) %>% 
  mutate(Percentage = `Big Sepals`/sum(`Big Sepals`)*100) %>% 
  mutate(Combined = paste0(`Big Sepals`, " (",round(Percentage, digits = 0), "%)"))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Species    `Big Sepals` Percentage Combined
#>   <fct>             <int>      <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 setosa               45       31.0 45 (31%)
#> 2 versicolor           50       34.5 50 (34%)
#> 3 virginica            50       34.5 50 (34%)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>